# Xorg freezes after some time on Dell XPS 9570

Tags: linux, xorg, laptop

I recently bought a Dell XPS 9570 and attempted installing PopOS on it alongside Windows 10 Pro. However, right after logging in the laptop would freeze and become completely unresponsive.
I eventually managed to install Arch Linux from TTY, but the system exhibits the same problem once I start X.Org - the computer would freeze 5-10 seconds after launching X Server.

What I've tried so far:

- Changing BIOS options (SATA operation - AHCI, POST Behavior - Fastboot (Thorough)
- Other distributions (Ubuntu, Fedora, GParted LiveCD)
- Updating BIOS and drivers from Windows (currently on the latest BIOS)
- Downgrading BIOS to 1.12.0
- Various bootloader options, here's what my kernel parameters currently look like: `quiet nouvea.modeset=0 nogpumanager pcie_aspm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! systemd.mask=mhwd-live.service acpi_rev_override=1 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.i915_psr=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1`
- Using LTS kernel
- Using dd mode instead of ISO mode in Rufus when flashing ISO to a USB drive

Unfortunately, none of this has helped and I'm only able to boot into TTY so far with no graphics.

**SSHing into the machine works, but shell becomes unresponsive after the freeze, indicating that it's not just X.Org crashing, but the whole system**

Here are the specs for my model:

- 4K Touch panel
- i7-8750H
- NVIDIA 1050 Ti Graphics

Comment: You probably need to install the proprietary [`nvidia`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA) driver. This should automatically blacklist the nouveau driver (reboot after installation).

Comment: @Freddy unfortunately that didn't help either

Comment: Better to stay with the original OS on it! And no other.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9570

Comment: @Freddy thank you, but as I said, I've already tried all the solutions described online, including this wiki page.

Comment: @Wolfgang Use a cable (Ethernet) to have internet and then **install the Nvidia drivers**. Yes, it can be done in tty and now there's an easy command to automatically install the recommended driver version in Ubuntu or derivatives (Google it).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've tried installing NVIDIA drivers on an Arch Linux installation but might try your suggestion on an Ubuntu LiveCD, thanks

Comment: @Wolfgang The suggestion is not for a live session and that would be a waste of time.  The reference to Ubuntu is because you started with a derivative, PopOS, and Arch seems to be a second thought, isn't it? The problem is that if can't manage to do such a simple thing in an Ubuntu based OS, expect it to be much harder in Arch.  And if you really want Arch for reasons then allow me to suggest Manjaro, a much more beginner friendly Arch based distribution that also has the advantage of (usually) installing the Nvidia drivers from the start.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm not sure you understood my question. I can't even boot into the LiveCD environment -- the whole system freezes as soon as I log into the DE.

Comment: @Wolfgang I understand your question.  You need 1. Be absolutely sure you're booting in UEFI mode and 2. Edit the "Try Ubuntu" (or whatever) and add `nomodeset`. I've done it dozens of times with that and similar hardware with high-end Nvidia graphics.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've tried doing that already. And yes, I am absolutely sure that I'm booting in UEFI mode

Comment: @Wolfgang Have you tried that parameter exactly as typed above? Curiously, not mentioned in the question (others yes, but not `nomodeset`, and almost all mentioned have really nothing to do with it)?? And if you really  did it was it before or after the UEFI upgrade? Downgrading was a really bad move. For more information I strongly suggest you search your exact model name plus Ubuntu. I'm sure you'll find lots of users detailing their experience ;) But I'm not here to promote Ubuntu. If you're happy with Arch, again, use Manjaro instead and it'll use and install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia My bad, I forgot to mention `nomodeset` in my post. Yes, I've tried it already, before and after downgrading. I realize that downgrading BIOS wasn't a smart move, but since a lot of users who reported success with Linux run older versions of firmware, I decided it was worth a try. I did try to search for solutions online and unfortunately all users with such problem report that `acpi_rev_override=1 nouveau.modeset=0` resolved their problems. In my case this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using the following kernel parameters:

```
acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2019"
```

Pay attention to the quotation marks: you need to escape them if you're running Grub, **but not if you're running systemd-boot**

If you're only using Intel graphics card you will also need to append `nouveau.modeset=0`

UPD: `acpi_osi="Windows 2019"` introduces a slight keyboard and trackpad lag and breaks the touchscreen